# Postgres 9.4+ jsonb: Index dictionaries nested in arrays

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

Given a table

```
create table tmp (data jsonb not null);
```

and data

```
insert into tmp (data) values ('{"root": [{"name": "item1"}, {"name": "item2"}]}');
```

I need to index jsonb column 'data' to quickly answer queries like

```
select * from tmp where data->'root' @> '[{"name": "item1"}]';
```

Is it possible in Postgres 9.4+?

Comment: `CREATE INDEX ON tmp((data->>'root'));`?

Comment: @Hackerman you were close: a correct solution appears  to be `data->'root'`.

Answer (score 6):

After a bit of debugging, I learned that indices created for outer json elements (e.g. "root") also apply to all the nested elements in the hierarchy. So the correct solution in my case is:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_tmp_data_root ON tmp USING gin ((data->'root') jsonb_path_ops);
```

I opted for `jsonb_path_ops` index operator class since it supports containment queries `@>` as required and results in a more compact and faster index as opposed to a default index type.

And here is a full demonstration:

First, create a table and load data:

```
-> SET enable_seqscan = OFF; -- force postgres to use indices if any
-> create temporary table tmp (data jsonb not null);
-> insert into tmp (data) values ('{"root": [{"name": "item1"}, {"name": "item2"}]}');
```

Query without an index:

```
-> explain select * from tmp where data->'root' @> '[{"name": "item1"}]';

QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on tmp  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000029.65 rows=1 width=32)
   Filter: ((data -> 'root'::text) @> '[{"name": "item1"}]'::jsonb)
(2 rows)
```

Query with an index:

```
-> CREATE INDEX idx_tmp_data_root ON tmp USING gin ((data->'root') jsonb_path_ops);
-> explain select * from tmp where data->'root' @> '[{"name": "item1"}]';

QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on tmp  (cost=8.00..12.02 rows=1 width=32)
  Recheck Cond: ((data -> 'root'::text) @> '[{"name": "item1"}]'::jsonb)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tmp_data_root  (cost=0.00..8.00 rows=1 width=0)
    Index Cond: ((data -> 'root'::text) @> '[{"name": "item1"}]'::jsonb)
(4 rows)

-> SET enable_seqscan = ON;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Well done, helped me a lot.